# jQuery - find certain attributes in json

Tags: jquery, json

I need to be able to identify certain attributes of a JSON response that is not always formatted the same way. A snippet of the example is:

```
{
   "Attributes" : [
      {
         "Value" : "4 bedrooms",
         "DisplayName" : "Bedrooms",
         "Name" : "bedrooms"
      },
      {
         "Value" : "2 bathrooms",
         "DisplayName" : "Bathrooms",
         "Name" : "bathrooms"
      },
      {
         "Value" : "House",
         "DisplayName" : "Property type",
         "Name" : "property_type"
      },
      {
         "Value" : "$780,000",
         "DisplayName" : "Rateable value",
         "Name" : "rateable_value"
      },
      {
         "Value" : "Price by negotiation",
         "DisplayName" : "Price",
         "Name" : "price"
      },
      {
         "Value" : "13 Wellswood Way\r\nLower Shotover\r\nQueenstown-Lakes\r\nOtago",
         "DisplayName" : "Location",
         "Name" : "location"
      },
      {
         "Value" : "Queenstown-Lakes",
         "DisplayName" : "District",
         "Name" : "district"
      },
      {
         "Value" : "Lower Shotover",
         "DisplayName" : "Suburb",
         "Name" : "suburb"
      },
      {
         "Value" : "Otago",
         "DisplayName" : "Region",
         "Name" : "region"
      },
      {
         "Value" : "254m²",
         "DisplayName" : "Floor area",
         "Name" : "floor_area"
      },
      {
         "Value" : "1690m²",
         "DisplayName" : "Land area",
         "Name" : "land_area"
      },
      {
         "Value" : "CBM959",
         "DisplayName" : "Property ID#",
         "Name" : "property_id"
      },
      {
         "Value" : "playground,tennis,hiking,biking,historic bridge walk,buses,5 mins to shops.",
         "DisplayName" : "In the area",
         "Name" : "in_the_area"
      },
      {
         "Value" : "Large double garage.Plenty off-street parking.Extra for boat+ etc.",
         "DisplayName" : "Parking",
         "Name" : "parking"
      }
   ]
}
```

---

As you can see the Name, DisplayName and Value are repeated for each attribute. What I don't know how to do is go through these attributes to find a particular one. For example, how would I get the value for Bathrooms?

Thanks for your help
Adam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example -

```
$(data.Attributes).each(function(index, element){
    if(element.Name == 'bathrooms')
        console.log(element.Value);
})
```

Demo - http://jsfiddle.net/PktXh/

Answer (score 1):

```
function getAttributesByName(arr,name){
    for(var i=0,l=arr.length;i<l;i++)
        if(arr[i].Name === name)
            return arr[i];
    return null;            
}
```

a more jquery approach :

```
function getAttributesByName(arr,name){
   var result = null;
   $.each(arr,function(){
       if(this.Name === name)
           result = this;
   });
   return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
var a = data.Attributes;
for(var i in a) {
    if(a.hasOwnProperty(i) && a[i].Name == 'bathrooms')
      return a[i].Value;
}
```